# Cannot build package goal due to source 1.5

Tags: java, maven

When I clean the project and run as clean, everything works fine. When I then try to run as build.. and set the goal to package I receive this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project smart.mirror: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Desktop/smart.mirror/src/main/java/iezon/smart/mirror/views/ApplicationView.java:[29,65] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Desktop/smart.mirror/src/main/java/iezon/smart/mirror/App.java:[119,49] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Desktop/smart.mirror/src/main/java/iezon/smart/mirror/views/Login.java:[86,51] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Desktop/smart.mirror/src/main/java/iezon/smart/mirror/views/Login.java:[136,49] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Desktop/smart.mirror/src/main/java/iezon/smart/mirror/views/Application.java:[88,65] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Desktop/smart.mirror/src/main/java/iezon/smart/mirror/views/Application.java:[158,103] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/Desktop/smart.mirror/src/main/java/iezon/smart/mirror/Application.java:[120,48] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
```

The multicatch on the majority of the lines look like this but when I run the application, the application works fine.

```
catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e)
```

I am unsure what sourcing 1.5 means, I have googled how to change Maven source on package build but can't find anything. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try configuring the maven-compiler-plugin directly, if you haven't included it explicitly already in your (super)pom.xml.
Add the following:

```
<build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
```

Comment: Build success after adding this to my `pom.xml`! Thanks a lot nkrieg, will accept answer when possible.

Comment: Nice answer. That source 1.5 is referring to Java version, while @nkrieg suggest to change it to 1.8 (Java 8).